# Tornado send and receive bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I'm writing a response in tornado of a string of bytes from an opened jpg file that go something like this:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\...
```

When I receive the bytes with `res = requests.get(url).text`, I get something like this:

```
����JFIF��C��C����  
���
��א�I+���`��;��oI�JU����J+��Uq̧[�}�ĥ�%��6A�}~�����mKD�#�
                                                       w,ޓW�t@~�?��TF�F������G�����N"���b��
```

When I try to escape it:

```
piece = tornado.escape.utf8(res)
OR
piece = res.encode()
```

I get a byte string, but it is not the same as what was sent:

```
b'\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x00C\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\...
```

This is how I am opening the original jpg:

```
with open('file.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    # Split content into multiple parts and send each part
```

How can I send and receive a series of bytes with tornado?

Comment: suggest to do a base64 of the content also for compression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = requests.get(url).text
```

You are trying to read the received JPEG file as a text file.

You need to use `content` attribute to get the data in bytes:

```
res = requests.get(url).content
```